# Why is "friend" needed in "operator<<()" overload definition?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, friend

```
class Train{
public: 
    char direction;
    int loading_time, crossing_time;        
    ...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Train& t){
        os << t.direction << '/' << t.loading_time << '/' << t.crossing_time;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Why is "friend" needed in this case? All attributes are public. Should I just use a struct instead?

Comment: `friend` is needed because the function is (inappropriately) defined inside the class. Without `friend` it would be a member function, with a different signature.

Comment: When defined this way, as an inline friend function, it is a [hidden friend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56796955/4641116) which is only accessible through ADL.  (Some teams or companies actively avoid ADL, and even possibly take steps to neutralize ADL from being utilized by the C++ compiler.  I'm okay with ADL, but something to be aware of.)

Comment: _"Why is "friend" needed in this case?"_  `friend` is [**not** needed in this case](https://godbolt.org/z/Evj57P1Tf).  `friend` grants access to a class's private members.  This function does not need such access.

Comment: @DrewDormann without "friend" it doesn't compile

Comment: @ChrisKouts please see it compiling successfully in the link in my last comment.  Making a function that doesn't need private access a `friend` serves no purpose and violates encapsulation.  It's not needed and I don't recommend it.

Comment: "serves no purpose" is incorrect. Hidden friends do have advantages.

Answer (score 5):

The `friend` is needed in order to make the function global. If you omit it, the function would be considered member function, in which case it should get only one parameter, and the caller should be of type `Train` (the class type in which we are declared), which doesn't fit our needs.

You can use in your case a global function instead:

```
class Train{
public: 
    char direction;
    int loading_time, crossing_time;        
    ...

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Train& t){
    os << t.direction << '/' << t.loading_time << '/' << t.crossing_time;
    return os;
}
```

However, it is very common to use a friend function for this use case (instead of a non-friend global function), as it is declared inside the class, which is an important side bonus that you get.

Comment: Not only “can use”, but “should use”. +1.

Comment: I think the point of making it a `friend` is to be able to access the data members.
normally they are `private`

Comment: @Tootsie — all the members of `Train` are public.

Comment: It is also common to use a (hidden) friend for this case to reduce overload sets, with potential benefits to compile time and to diagnostics.